# How to change your primary device for receiving the verification code?

Tags: mac

My MacBookPro(primary device for receiving verification codes for other devices) crashed and I have to replace the hard drive.
How do I make my Mac-Mini my primary device?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research online, I was unable to find any mention of a "Primary Device". Any device that is registered to receive Two Step verification codes will receive the code.

I think what you need to do to receive the codes on you Mac-Mini is register the device to receive Two Step Verification codes.

**Step Up device to receive Two Step Verification Codes:**

1. Go to Apple () menu > System Preferences > iCloud > Account Details
2. Click Security.
3. Click Turn On Two-Factor Authentication.

Instructions from [Apple KB - Two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/HT204915)

Hope this helps